# Permissions required to upload alpha/beta apks to play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have been granted the following permissions within a Play Store account to a particular application:

- Edit Store Listing, ...
- Manage Alpha & Beta apks
- Manage Alpha & Beta users
- Manage Production apks

( I don't have create & edit draft apps permission)

However the Alpha & Beta testing tabs for the application are greyed out.  As is the Upload production apk button.

What particular permission do I need in addition to the above in order for the alpha & beta tabs to become active?

And also for the Upload production apk button to become active?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually the permissions were fine.  Access was prevented due to issues with the app's store listing.  Once these were resolved, things started working as expected.